# PCL installation problems

Tags: vtk, pcl

I tried to install PCL1.13.1 to run the project "Loam_Livox", but when I use cmake, it come with the error below:
Missing vtk modules: vtkRenderingOpenGL2;vtkRenderingContextOpenGL2
what I can do to deal with this? Thanks a lot

I reinstalled VTK7.1.1 but the error still exist, my OS is Ubuntu18.04

Comment: How did you install VTK?